# Tikz externalisation - space in file name

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external

I have a `main.tex`file that includes a bunch of `chapterX.tex` files where X is the chapter number. The chapter files include files with tikz code.

In a package included by the main file I set a prefix for tikz to externalise images to. What I would like to do is

```
 \tikzsetnextfilename{Chapter 2/Image}
```

in the tikz files to make sure the image is placed in the `Chapter 2` subdirectory (within the path specified by the prefix). However, it seems that the space between `Chapter`and `2`is causing problems as my project won't compile:

```
! Argument of \language@active@arg" has an extra }.
```

If I remove the space it works fine although for some reason log files are generated in the directory specified by the prefix as well.  I've tried putting "" around the path but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just avoid spaces in directory paths? It's a good habit to get into anyway.

Comment: I can do that. Unfortunately the log file, md5 file etc. are created twice - once in the intended directory (.../Chapter2) and once in the parent directory (which is specified by the prefix. So I'll probably have to set the directory and file name in each separate .tex file with tikz content which is not ideal.

Comment: I have a similar problem, I'm using LyX and if I put only `\tikzexternalize[prefix=Figures/]` all works but the files are stored in a LyX temp dir, so I loose them when I close LyX (making externalization useless). Unfortunately the path where I would like to put them begins with C:\Users\Name Surname\ and I can't rename it (Windows 10). I've tried in many ways but all of them give me error.