# Trig Function not compiling externalized pgfplots

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, tikz-external

I am trying to graph a rational trig function using tikz/pgfplots and got the error that it ran out of memory. I then changed my pdflatex line in TexMaker to "pdflatex -shell-escape name.tex" and tried to compile, and while I haven't run into a memory issue yet, it is still compiling after about 15 minutes. Is there something I can do about this or do I just need to let it run overnight?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{verbatim,amsfonts, colonequals, amsthm, amsmath, mathrsfs, amscd, pgfplots,multicol,geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\geometry{textwidth=6.3in,textheight=9in}

\parindent=0in
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-4:4, samples=128] {cos(x)/(2+sin(x))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: I didn't end up using the deg option as I actually wanted radians, but the issue was with the -shell-escape externalization. If anyone runs into this issue, the solution for my problem was reaming the file so that it has no spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which of the many style files you include make your minimal working example minimal. Apart from that, there are two issues: `domain:-4:-4` doesn't make too much sense and probably you want to convert the arguments of the trigonometric functions. This works:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepgfplotslibrary{external} 
\tikzexternalize

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.75]
\begin{axis}
\addplot[domain=-4:4, samples=128] {cos(deg(x))/(2+sin(deg(x)))};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The styles are leftover from the main file I am using, I simply forgot to delete them. Also, the -4:-4 was a typo and it should be -4:4. I've tried running your example and i'll still stuck compiling for what seems to be an unusual amount of time.

Comment: @JohnC Interesting. On my machine it takes less than a second. Are you compiling with `-shell-escape`? (I am using `pdflatex -shell-escape`.) Do the other documents compile on your machine?

Comment: "pdflatex -shell-escape Trig Graph.tex" where Trig Graph is the name of this example file I am using. My other tex documents compile just fine when I am using the normal "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Comment: @JohnC I hope that there is not as space in your prompt. If yes, try `pdflatex -shell-escape Trig\ Graph.tex`, i.e. add a backslash, since otherwise the `pdflatex` will try to compile `Trig.tex`.

Comment: I can't get your suggestion to work with a space in the file name but if I change the file to Trig.tex and compile, it works. Any idea why it won't run even when using backslashes?

Comment: @JohnC Can you try a file name without space(s)?

Comment: I wasn't clear. I did try that and it worked, and if need be I can just rename the original file, but out of curiosity, I'm trying to see if we could get it to compile with a space in the file name.

Comment: @JohnC Oh, I see. I do not now, but given that [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/233072/121799) does not have an answer, I would not be very optimistic.